# How to restart the killed logstash process using ps -ef | grep -i 'logstash' kill -9 logstash?

Tags: shell, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, elk

I killed realtime logstash pipeline using this command

```
ps -ef | grep -i 'logstash' 
 kill -9 logstash
```

I have to restart the pipeline now.

How to do it?

Comment: _Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers._ There are other sites in the [SE network](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology) better suited for this kind of questions, [Superuser](https://superuser.com/) probably.

Comment: Question is not clear, you want to say that you have no idea what kind of command was used to start the pipeline? In that case you have to find it somewhere on the system and everything else is said by @JamesBrown

Answer (score 0):

if you've killed Logstash then you will need to restart the service

how you do that is dependant on your OS;

- linux https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/running-logstash.html
- windows https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/running-logstash-windows.html